# how to test for moderation effects comparing two regression models?

Tags: logistic, interaction

I collected data about consumers website usage behavior and reaction to online advertising for mobile and desktop devices. My goal is to analyze how consumers website usage in reaction to online advertising is moderated by the choice of device.

First, I conducted independent t-tests to show that the usage behavior significantly differs (in terms of visit time and other variables) expect for the number of page views. Therefore I ran afterwards two logistic regression models (dv = click or no ad click) for each subsample (mobile and desktop) in order to examine how the website usage for each device is influencing the click response.

The logistic regression models are similar and look like this:

```
lm(ad_response ~ page_views + visit_durarion + ... + referer_type)
```

The results for both models indicate that the visit duration and number of page views have an significant influence on consumers click response.

Now, my question is: *How can I compare these two models in order to determine the moderation effect?*  (**Edit:** Or in other words: How can I compare logit and probit coefficients between models and across groups?)

Would it make sense to run an additional logit regression model combining both devices and that only examines the interaction effect (i.e. running a logit model only including interaction effects without any main effects)? As far as I understand I can't just run a single model including all website usage variables because:

1. They are not homogenous for smartphones and desktops (except for number of page views).
2. Without the device there couldn't be any website usage behavior observed.

Help is greatly appreciated. Feel free to ask me anything for further clarification.

Comment: thank you! :) any hints, how I could solve this problem?